# PHP returns &#65279; html entity on print functions

Tags: php, character-encoding

Always when I use print/print_r/echo/var_dump and etc. my php file adds `&#65279;` at the end of the text. For example: `echo 'a';`, will return `a&#65279;`.
Trying to reinstall php didn't help.
Encoding of the file is UTF-8 with BOM. Without BOM, it returns ï»¿ at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This entity represents the BOM (Byte Order Mark, Unicode name "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE"). However,

1. it should be at the very beginning of the file;
2. it shouldn't be escaped as an HTML entity, but written as a plain character.

So something is clearly going wrong when encoding your file.

The character sequence "ï»¿" is what the BOM looks like when it is encoded with UTF-8, but erroneously interpreted as Latin-1.

This might help you understand the problem.
In order to help you fix this, you need to provide more details/context on what exactly you are doing. For example, where/how do specify the encoding of the output file?

Comment: I just realized that if I try to print something in whatever file this Unicode character would appear. I'm using git and I'm on windows. Could it be a cause of a problem?

Comment: If the encoding is something "with BOM", then this character is supposed to be there – as the very first character, and not escaped – because that's what "with BOM" means. On Windows, I have seen that "UTF8" was used as a label for what is actually "UTF8 with BOM". I wouldn't expect git to be responsible for inadequate BOM intrusion. Again: in order for me to help you, you need to show how you open a file, how you write to it, and how you inspect it afterwards.